# "Page not found" all over the place with i18n on Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, internationalization, multilingual

I am clearly missing the picture here as just about everything I try is just failing miserably. I have languages as follows:

```
gb-en - UK English (path = /gb/en/about )
us-en - US English (path = /us/en/about )
us-es - US Spanish (path = /us/es/about )
```

I have an about page located at /about. If I translate and assign the links above, two things go wrong:

1. If I go to the translate page, and say I want to translate it to "US-ES", then the link becomes: 
   us/es/node/add/page?translation=6&target=us-es --> which does not exist (page not found)
2. If I add the language switcher, and switch to the US-ES page that it has found, it also says "page not found".

Something is causing everything to say "page not found" and I have fiddled with just about everything in the settings and it just doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Could it perhaps be because I am using prefixes with slashes? I.e. us/en and us/es etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i18n module does not work if you set the prefix as A/B, only as A. In other words, you can have this:

```
/us-en
```

But not this

```
/us/en
```

Which is really annoying and I wish it didn't work this way, or that someone at least added validation so you can be told not to do this on the settings page.